# Convert String to datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, django

I have an input string as hundreds or thousand of hours, such as:

```
1000:50 (One thousand hours and 50 minutes)
```

I need to convert it into a timedelta object, in order to insert it as a DurationField in a Django Model.
So far, what I tried is to use datetime.strptime but, the error is giving me is:

```
time data '1000:50' does not match format '%H:%M'
```

I tried to google any kind of solution but so far I didn't find a solution that could help me. Even though the DurationField will convert the timedelta in number of days, I just need to have the input to be as thousand or hundreds of hours, after that, the calculation will be handled in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because `%H` [only for 24 hours](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime) format, i.e. 0...23

To solve your particular problem, I'd extract hours and minutes from string via regular expressions

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta


your_string = "1000:50 (One thousand hours and 50 minutes)"
hours, minutes = re.findall('(\d+):(\d+)', your_string)[0]
duration = timedelta(hours=int(hours), minutes=int(minutes))
```